# i receive this error when i try 2 install a package through software-center any help plz

Tags: software-center, policykit

Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.124'}): org.debian.apt.install-file

Comment: Can you try running this in a terminal: sudo /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 and then try installing through software-center again

Comment: you probably don't have polkit installed, can you run "dpkg -l |grep polkit" and see if you have it installed pls?